# Read and write serial port on Linux

Tags: go, serial-port

I use `github.com/jacobsa/go-serial/serial` package to work with serial port in my Go program.

Simplified example:

```
options := serial.OpenOptions{
        PortName: "/dev/ttyUSB0",
        BaudRate: 115200,
        DataBits: 8,
        StopBits: 1,
        MinimumReadSize = 0,
        InterCharacterTimeout = 100,
    }       


    port, _ := serial.Open(options)
    defer port.Close()

    res := make([]byte, 1024)
    var err error
    var i int = 0

    for i == 0 {
        i, err = port.Read(res)
        if err != nil && err != io.EOF {
            log.Printf("port.Read: %v", err)
            err = errors.New("I/O error")
        }

}
log.Println("Read bytes: ", i)

// do something else
```

When data is not ready, we have `io.EOF` error. But, when there is connection lost, there is also `io.EOF` errror! How could I distinguish waiting for new data and disconnection? If there is no data, FOR cycle need to be continue untill timeout is reached, but if connection is lost, I need to re-open port, because it's descriptor becames wrong. What is the good practice to handle these cases?

Comment: Start by fixing the usage of the [`io.Reader`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#Reader) according the documentation. How do you know you have an `io.EOF`? There's no code path here that checks for an EOF? There should not be a case where an `io.Reader` returns `n == 0` without an error.

Comment: FYI, the language is called "Go". "golang" is a token recognized by a popular Internet search engine.

Comment: Right you are, "Go" is the right name. But let's go to the subject.

Comment: Now, I try manually handle disconections. But, I can not discover a good practice.  In the code of my app, once created descriptor "walks" from one function to another,  while it desposes by defer func. Thus, if I manually try to reconnect (close and re-create connection), all the stack of function calls gets a bad file descriptor. Is there a way to re-connect?

Comment: related, although using `github.com/tarm/serial`: [Golang reading from serial](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50088669/10197418)