# Golang reading from serial

Tags: go, serial-port

I'm trying to read from a serial port (a GPS device on a Raspberry Pi).

Following the instructions from http://www.modmypi.com/blog/raspberry-pi-gps-hat-and-python

I can read from shell using

```
stty -F /dev/ttyAMA0 raw 9600 cs8 clocal -cstopb
cat /dev/ttyAMA0
```

I get well formatted output

```
$GNGLL,5133.35213,N,00108.27278,W,160345.00,A,A*65
$GNRMC,160346.00,A,5153.35209,N,00108.27286,W,0.237,,290418,,,A*75
$GNVTG,,T,,M,0.237,N,0.439,K,A*35
$GNGGA,160346.00,5153.35209,N,00108.27286,W,1,12,0.67,81.5,M,46.9,M,,*6C
$GNGSA,A,3,29,25,31,20,26,23,21,16,05,27,,,1.11,0.67,0.89*10
$GNGSA,A,3,68,73,83,74,84,75,85,67,,,,,1.11,0.67,0.89*1D
$GPGSV,4,1,15,04,,,34,05,14,040,21,09,07,330,,16,45,298,34*40
$GPGSV,4,2,15,20,14,127,18,21,59,154,30,23,07,295,26,25,13,123,22*74
$GPGSV,4,3,15,26,76,281,40,27,15,255,20,29,40,068,19,31,34,199,33*7C
$GPGSV,4,4,15,33,29,198,,36,23,141,,49,30,172,*4C
$GLGSV,3,1,11,66,00,325,,67,13,011,20,68,09,062,16,73,12,156,21*60
$GLGSV,3,2,11,74,62,177,20,75,53,312,36,76,08,328,,83,17,046,25*69
$GLGSV,3,3,11,84,75,032,22,85,44,233,32,,,,35*62
$GNGLL,5153.35209,N,00108.27286,W,160346.00,A,A*6C
$GNRMC,160347.00,A,5153.35205,N,00108.27292,W,0.216,,290418,,,A*7E
$GNVTG,,T,,M,0.216,N,0.401,K,A*3D
$GNGGA,160347.00,5153.35205,N,00108.27292,W,1,12,0.67,81.7,M,46.9,M,,*66
$GNGSA,A,3,29,25,31,20,26,23,21,16,05,27,,,1.11,0.67,0.89*10
$GNGSA,A,3,68,73,83,74,84,75,85,67,,,,,1.11,0.67,0.89*1D
$GPGSV,4,1,15,04,,,34,05,14,040,21,09,07,330,,16,45,298,34*40
```

(I've put some random data in)

I'm trying to read this in Go.  Currently, I have

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "log"
import "github.com/tarm/serial"

func main() {
        config := &serial.Config{
                Name: "/dev/ttyAMA0",
                Baud: 9600,
                ReadTimeout: 1,
                Size: 8,
        }

        stream, err := serial.OpenPort(config)
        if err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
        }

        buf := make([]byte, 1024)

        for {
                n, err := stream.Read(buf)
                if err != nil {
                        log.Fatal(err)
                }
                s := string(buf[:n])
                fmt.Println(s)
        }
}
```

But this prints malformed data.  I suspect that this is due to the buffer size or the value of `Size` in the `config` struct being wrong, but I'm not sure how to get those values from the `stty` settings.

Looking back, I think the issue is that I'm getting a stream and I want to be able to iterate over lines of the stty, rather than chunks.  This is how the stream is outputted:

```
$GLGSV,3
,1,09,69
,10,017,
,70,43,0
69,,71,3
2,135,27
,76,23,2
32,22*6F

$GLGSV
,3,2,09,
77,35,30
0,21,78,
11,347,,
85,31,08
1,30,86,
72,355,3
6*6C
$G
LGSV,3,3
,09,87,2
4,285,30
*59
$GN
GLL,5153
.34919,N
,00108.2
7603,W,1
92901.00
,A,A*6A
```

Comment: In what was is the data it prints malformed? Can you show an example? And what is the specific question? How to read the buffer size from the stty?

Comment: Thinking about it, malformed seems to be the wrong word, it seem that the line delimitation isn't done

Comment: I'm also running into this issue, but unfortunately I can't seem to solve it. I get the awkward formatting like this with a variety of serial libraries I've tried. Anyone happen to figure out a solution?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The struct you get back from `serial.OpenPort()` contains a pointer to an open `os.File` corresponding to the opened serial port connection. When you `Read()` from this, the library calls `Read()` on the underlying `os.File`.

The [documentation for this function call](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#File.Read) is:

> Read reads up to len(b) bytes from the File. It returns the number of bytes read and any error encountered. At end of file, Read returns 0, io.EOF.

This means you have to keep track of how much data was read. You also have to keep track of whether there were newlines, if this is important to you. Unfortunately, the underlying `*os.File` is not exported, so you'll find it difficult to use tricks like `bufio.ReadLine()`. It may be worth modifying the library and sending a pull request.

---

As Matthew Rankin noted in a comment, `Port` implements `io.ReadWriter` so you can simply use `bufio` to read by lines.

```
    stream, err := serial.OpenPort(config)
    if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
    }

    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(stream)
    for scanner.Scan() {
        fmt.Println(scanner.Text()) // Println will add back the final '\n'
    }
    if err := scanner.Err(); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
```

Comment: Why do you state that "you'll find it difficult to use tricks like `bufio.ReadLine()`"? Even though `*os.File` isn't exported, the `Port` struct meets the io.ReadWriter interface, so you can use `bufio.NewReader(port)`.

Comment: @MatthewRankin You're right, it does. That makes things much easier. Not sure why I didn't notice that previously. I might have been accidentally looking at an old revision of the code or something.

Answer (score 4):

Change

```
fmt.Println(s)
```

to

```
fmt.Print(s)
```

and you will probably get what you want.
Or did I misunderstand the question?