# Connect to usb device

Tags: go, serial-port

I have a device that connected to my pc over usb-B. And I have a piece of code that can work with it on windows.

On windows we get COM name by vid and pid and use `tarm/serial` package for connection. But I can't connect to the device on linux same way neither via `ttyACM0` nor `ttyACM1`

I'm trying to do:

```
&serial.Config{
            Name: "/dev/ttyACM1",
            Baud: configuration.ReceiptPrinterBaud,
            ReadTimeout: time.Second * 2,
        },
```

But when I read from port with `(p *Port) Read()`, I'm getting nothing.
Obviously, I just send bytes to nowhere. How can I interact with the device on linux like on windows?

Comment: Related/duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/49260737/13860

Comment: Looks like a driver issue, type `dmesg | grep /dev/tty*` right after plugging the device in to see if the driver is loaded or you are getting any errors

Comment: Can you post the output of `lsusb -v` regarding your device?

Comment: Maybe it's a permissions issue? It's common with serial devices on linux. Check that your user has permissions to access /dev/ttyACM1. Also check that you're handling errors properly in the Go code, you should be able to see the permission denied error if that's the issue.